# Can OnCloseQuery protect data loss

Tags: delphi

H1 I have written a little process to save data before `Application.Terminate` using `OnCloseQuery`. I was wondering whether this is sufficient in the event of a power failure or a computer crash.

```
type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        abs: TABSDatabase;
        ABSTable1: TABSTable;
        .... 
        ABSTable6: TABSTable;
    ....    
var
Form1: TForm1;
isBusy : Boolean;
....
procedure TForm1.CloseTables;
 var
    x : Integer;
    dummy : TABSTable;
begin
     for x:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
     begin
         if Components[x] is TABSDataSet then
             begin
                 if Components[x] is TABSTable  then
                 begin
                     dummy := (Components[x] as TABSTable);
                     if ((dummy.Active = True) and ((dummy.state = dsEdit) or (dummy.State = dsInsert))) then
                         begin
                             dummy.Post;
                             dummy.Active := False;
                         end
                       else
                         if dummy. Active = True then dummy.Close;                               
                 end;
             end;
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
        if abs.Connected = True then isBusy := True else isBusy := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
    if isBusy = True then
        begin
            CanClose := False;
            CloseTables;
            abs.Connected := False;
            isBusy := False;
            Application.Terminate;
        end
        else CanClose := True;
end;
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

I modified my code following David Heffernan's advice.

```
procedure TForm1.CloseTables;
 var
  x : Integer;
  dummy : TABSTable;
begin
   for x:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
   begin
     if Components[x] is TABSDataSet then
       begin
         if Components[x] is TABSTable  then
          begin
            dummy := (Components[x] as TABSTable);
            if ((dummy.Active) and ((dummy.state = dsEdit) or (dummy.State = dsInsert))) then
              begin
                dummy.Post;
                dummy.Active := False;
              end
            else
              if dummy.Active then dummy.Close;
          end;
       end;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if abs.Connected then
    begin
      CanClose := False;
      CloseTables;
      abs.Connected := False;
      Application.Terminate;
    end
  else CanClose := True;
end;
```

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me that you wouldn't get better behaviour if you removed all of this code. By the way don't write `if foo = True then`, write `if foo then`. Also don't write `if foo then bar := True else bar := False`, write `bar := foo`

Comment: Nothing can help if your computer loses power or crashes.

Comment: Also `isBusy` is a global here but should be a form member variable. It's also probably not necessary. Can't you just test `abs.Connected` directly?

Comment: If power failure concerns you overly, buy a ups

Comment: @David Heffernan thank you for that logical statement. I remember seeing something like it before but couldn't find it. Should I close this question

Comment: @David Heffernan Pardon my continuing ignorance but what is a form member variable? I.ve just tried googling it but cannot find a reference. Is the variable declared in the public section?

Comment: Suppose you have a class {{TFrog}} in your frog simulator application. Then you create ten thousand instances of this -- that is, you create ten thousand frogs that jump around on your screen. Each frog has its own weight, colour, and age: these are _instance variables_, that is, each instance of the {{TFrog}} class -- each frog -- has its own such variable. On the other hand, your application may have a global time of day or weather variable -- there is only one such in your entire application, no matter how many frogs you have.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, thank you for your helpful example.

Answer (score 1):

> this is sufficient in the event of a power failure or a computer crash

No, not at all.

After answering that question let's take a look where [`OnCloseQuery`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/OnCloseQuery_(Delphi)) is triggered at all, so you can sense what else you might miss:

- (At least in Delphi 5) It is invoked when the *Windows* session was about to end and every running process was asked to close gracefully:

  ```pascal
  procedure TCustomForm.WMQueryEndSession(var Message: TWMQueryEndSession);
  begin
    Message.Result := Integer(CloseQuery and CallTerminateProcs);
  end;
  ```

  > The [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) message is sent when the user chooses to end the session or when an application calls one of the system shutdown functions. If any application returns zero, the session is not ended.
- When [`.Close()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Close) is called - the typical call to close one of your windows (forms).
- When internally [`.CloseModal()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CloseModal) is called.

Keep in mind that something as easy as [`TerminateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) will kill your running program without letting it any chance of still executing instructions. Furthermore using [`SuspendThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-suspendthread) on your main program's thread can also hang it right there infinitly, so your code isn't executed either.

Answer (score 0):

A comment was made that nothing can help if you lose power or the computer crashes. That is not completely correct. But the only things that can help in such cases are:

- A [UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply), as [David Heffernan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471946/can-onclosequery-protect-data-loss#comment131464396_74471946) (which will only help in the case of a power failure).
- Saving data periodically instead of waiting for the form or application to close.

In the latter case, there are two potential problems:

- You will still lose any unsaved data since the last periodical save (which will be minimised if you save frequently).
- The power fails or the computer crashes *during* a periodical save.  Depending on your requirement this might be an acceptable risk, but the way to avoid this problem is to save in a different place each time, perhaps deleting the previous periodical save after the latest periodical save has successfully completed.

Databases usually support transactions (mostly known as `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`, see [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)), so when a power loss occures during saving data it is "just" lost but never overwrites or invalidates previous saves.